# JSLint variables declaration and JSDoc in PhpStorm

Tags: jslint, phpstorm, jsdoc

How to make PhpStorm understand the types of the variables declared like that:

```js
function presentation() {
    "use strict";
    var
        /** @type {Number} */
        a,
        /** @type {jQuery} */
        b,
        /** @type {HTMLAnchorElement} */
        c;
}
```

PhpStorm only knows the last variable type and suggests its methods / attributes, but it has no idea about the type of the variables "a" and "b".

Is it possible to document types in PhpStorm and be JSLint compliant? If so, how?